# Cross correlation gives incorrect result in scipy, python

Tags: python, scipy, cross-correlation

I have a vector `x` with numbers and then I create a shifted copy and perform cross correlation, but yet I get that the lag with highest correlation is 0. I've tried to do the same with a vector with normally distributed numbers of the same size and then it works. I've also noticed that if I just use a smaller part of the vector it also works...

```
def align_time_series(a, b):
    mode="full"
    correlation = signal.correlate(a, b, mode=mode)
    lags = correlation_lags(a.size, b.size, mode=mode)
    lags_corr = pd.Series(correlation, lags)
    lags_corr.plot()
    print(lags_corr.idxmax())
    plt.axvline(lags_corr.idxmax())
    plt.show()

y = x[2000:]
align_time_series(x, y)
# => best lag is 0?
```

Comment: It is a vector of around 26000 numbers between 50 and 110. Should it matter what the data is? @Mr.T

Comment: As far as I'm aware the algorithm should work on all types data, but perhaps it doesn't. @Mr.T

Comment: @Mr.T it is not random noise, it is a clear trend actually.